# proof by induction: $7^{2n} - 2^n$ is always divisible by $47$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility

as per the title, i need to prove by induction that the expression "$7^{2n} - 2^n$" is always divisible by $47$.

base case is fine: $7^{2*1} - 2^1 = 47$.

Induction step gets lost quickly, any ideas?

step 1: $7^{2(n+1)} - 2^{(n+1)}$

step 2:  $7^2 * 7^{2n} - 2^1 * 2^{n}$

step 3: ???

step 4: profit.

Comment: This meme never gets old.

Comment: Induction? Why? Just note that$$7^{2n}-2^n=49^n-2^n=(49-2)\times(49^{n-1}+49^{n-2}\times2+\cdots+49\times2^{n-2}+2^{n-1}).$$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos could possibly be an exercise in the technique of proofs by induction

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Probably. But I think that it is an abomination to provide, when introducing students to proofs by induction, exercices which admit a more natural proof without induction rather than with.

Comment: Isn't $$ (49-2)\mid (49^n-2^n)$$ pretty trivial?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos but don't blame the messenger :-)

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Hey! I didn't downvote the question. ;-)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Sure it is.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Oh, I wasn't accusing you of downvoting.  I hadn't even noticed the downvote.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Actually, I only noticed it *after* writing what I wrote.

Comment: I see an elementary number theory tag- are you familiar with modular congruence? Granted, this also sort of subverts the induction part of the proof.

Comment: "Isn't
$(49−2)∣(49^n−2^n)$
pretty trivial?"  It may or may not be.  But recognizing that is the pivotal key takes insight and experience and, probably, practice.

Comment: @KevinLong im sorry to have to admit this, but i saw the tag on a couple of questions which were similar to mine, and added it with the intention that it would help circulate my question in the relevant fields. So in short, no i am not familiar with modular congruence.

Comment: modular congruence is great!  $a \equiv b \mod n$ means i) $a$ and $b$ have the same remainder when divided by $n$ or ii)$n|(a-b)$ or ii)$a = kn+b;n\in\mathbb Z$. so $n|a\iff a\equiv 0\mod n$. It's easy to show modular equations "carry" through addition, multiplication, and powers so if $a\equiv b \mod n$ the $a^k\equiv b^k \mod n$.  So $7^{2n}-2^n=49^n-2^n\equiv 2^n-2^n\mod 47 \equiv 0 \mod 7$.  Can't get much easier than that.... once you learn modular congruence.

Comment: ... or in other words $7^{2n} - 2^n=49^n-2^n=(47+2)^n-2^n$.  Now $(a+b)^n = a^n + n*a^{n-1}b+{n\choose 2}a^{n-1}b^2 + ...... + {n\choose 2}a^2{b-2} + n*a*b^{n-1} + b^n$ and $a$ divides *all* those terms but the last so $(47+2)^n = 47^n + n*47^{n-1}*2 + ...... + 47*2^{n-1}+ 2^n= 47*K+2^n$ where $K = ... $whatever.  So $7^{2n}-2^n=49^n-2^n=(47-2)^n - 2^n=47K + 2^n-2^n = 47K$.

Comment: thanks @fleablood, you really helped my understanding beyond the scope of my original question. It pains me that I cannot accept two answers as solutions here. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 is **not** “$7^{2(n+1)} - 2^{n+1}$.”  You're thinking in terms of *expressions* and you want to think in terms of *sentences*.  This is one half of the conclusion to an if-then statement you want to prove:

> For any $n$, if $7^{2n} - 2^n$ is divisible by $47$, then $7^{2(n+1)} - 2^{n+1}$ is also divisible by $47$.

Step 0 is the base case, which you have shown.

Step 1 is “Suppose there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $7^{2n} = 2^n$.”

Step 2 is: you need to show that $7^{2(n+1)} - 2^{n+1}$ is divisible by $47$.

You've got a few answers on how to show that.  Essentially it's the old add-and-subtract-the-same-thing trick.
\begin{align*}
    7^{2n+2} - 2^{n+1} &= 7^2\cdot 7^{2n} - 2\cdot 2^{n} 
\\&= 7^2 \cdot 7^{2n} - 7^2 \cdot 2^n + 7^2 \cdot 2^n - 2\cdot 2^n
\\&= 49 (7^{2n} - 2^{n}) + 47 \cdot 2^n
\end{align*}
If $7^{2n} - 2^{n} = 47k$ for some integer $k$, then
$$
    49 (7^{2n} - 2^{n}) + 47 \cdot 2^n = 49\cdot 47k + 47 \cdot 2^n = 47(49k + 2^n)
$$
in other words, also a multiple of $47$.

Step 3 is “Therefore, by induction, $7^{2n} - 2^n$ is divisible by $47$ for all positive integers $n$.”

If you follow these steps, and apply them to all proofs by induction, you will indeed *profit*.

Comment: PS I am challenging A---B's assertion that this meme never gets old.  I saw the Underpants Gnomes episode live in 1998.  It's even older than the word *meme*.

Comment: You saw an animated show live?  And the word "meme" dates to the 70s.  It just wasn't common until it was applied to internet themes which does post date Underwear Gnomes, but then if you are sticking to internet themes as the definition... this isn't a meme as television is not internet.

Comment: You're right, of course.  By *live* I meant "when it first aired," and by *was a word* I meant *was a household word.*  Please forgive my sloppiness.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @egreg.

Comment: Oh, I'm just busting your chops.  It's what I do.

Comment: What I really meant to say was "I feel old." :--)

Answer (score 0):

$$7^{2n}-2^n=49^n-2^n=(49-2)(49^{n-1}+...+2^{n-1})$$ is divisible by $47$.

Answer (score 0):

it is $$(7^2)^n-2^n=49^n-2^n\equiv 2^n-2^n\equiv 0 \mod 47$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For the induction step:

$7^{2n+2}-2^{n+1}=49\cdot 7^{2n}-2\cdot 2^{n}=47\cdot 7^{2n}+2(7^{2n}-2^n)$

Answer (score 0):

Matthew Leingang’s answer is very good, but it can be simplified: there is no need to guess what to add and subtract.

The induction hypothesis that $7^{2n}-2^n$ is divisible by $47$ can be written as
$$
7^{2n}-2^n=47k
$$
for some $k$. Therefore $7^{2n}=47k+2^n$ and so
\begin{align}
7^{2(n+1)}-2^{n+1}
&=7^2\cdot 7^{2n}-2^{n+1}\\[4px]
&=49\cdot(47k+2^n)-2^{n+1}\\[4px]
&=47\cdot49k+49\cdot2^n-2^{n+1}\\[4px]
&=47\cdot 49k+(49-2)\cdot2^n\\[4px]
&=47(49k+2^n)
\end{align}
is divisible by $47$.

Answer (score -1):

Step 1:  $7^{2(n+1)} - 2^{n+1}$

Step 2: $7^2*7^{2n} - 2*2^n$.

Step 3: $(47 + 2)7^{2n} - 2*2^n=47*7^{2n} + 2(7^{2n} - 2^n)$

Step 4: Profit.

(BTW... you miswrote this as $7^{2n} - 2^{2n}$ which is not true.)